# reorient an object's axes

Tags: transforms

I have some furniture assets in a Unity VR Scene (chairs and benches, etc.) I am trying to enable sitting on the chairs. The current orientation is incorrect for this to occur. The chair is rotated 90 deg on the x axis in order to appear upright in Unity.

I need to "green" axis to be vertical and the "blue" axis to be forward.

Can anyone point me to anything that explains how I can do this. I'm not good at this at all so easy is best. Thanks.

Comment: I do believe the answer is in there. I didn't see those settings. Thanks.